# Is there any way to get all the keys in an angular $cacheFactory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cachefactory

I know there is another library called angular-cache on npm/bower. But adding a new library is quite a process where I work. So I want to use $cacheFactory's or core Javascript functions to solve this.

I saw a lot of responses in stackoverflow for getting all the keys of a hasmap, so I tried this:

```
var keys = [];
for(var key in parameterCache) {
    keys.push(key);
    console.log(key);
}
```

The outputs on the console were weird. They were the names of functions in $cacheFactory (remove, destroy, info etc.)

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in way of listing all keys from a `$cacheFactory` instance and there are [no plans to include this to the core library](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3760#issuecomment-223905896), so you will have to either use a replacement such as [angular-cache](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache) library or add these methods by yourself. I needed to add this functionality to my $http cache and I couldn't find a way to do this cleanly (with decorators or something) so I had to resort to monkey-patching it in my `.run()` block:

```
// create a new $cacheFactory instance 
var httpWithKeysCacheFactory = $cacheFactory('$httpWithKeys'),
// save the original put() method
    originalPut = httpWithKeysCacheFactory.put;
// add a property to hold cache keys
httpWithKeysCacheFactory.keys = [];
// overwrite put() with a custom method
httpWithKeysCacheFactory.put = function (key, value) {
// call original put() and save the key
    if (originalPut(key, value)) {
        this.keys.push(key);
    }
};
// tell $http to use your monkey-patched cache factory
$http.defaults.cache = httpWithKeysCacheFactory;
```

Doing so allowed me to access my cache keys from a controller like this:

```
$cacheFactory.get('$httpWithKeys').keys;
```

Note: this is a very naive approach that does not check for key duplicates and does not modify `remove()` and `removeAll()` methods to update keys when an entry is removed from cache.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this module : [angular-cache](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache)

So you can use this CacheFactory.keys() wich return you all id of registered caches